# Can't run jenkins slave on ECS fargate

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm using Amazon Elastic Container Service plugin which allows running Jenkins slaves on AWS ECS. Functionality which allows running slaves on EC2 type of ECS works perfectly, but I can't run slaves on Fargate. Tasks in the cluster are not created and no any activity in the ECS cluster at all. Can anyone share configurations of Amazon Elastic Container Service plugin which successfully works with Fargate, or help with an issue?

Comment: Looks like there is bug in this plugin if you try to set up task definition from Jenkins. But I have seen many people who created a task definition in AWS & referred same in Jenkins with Task-Definition Override option, works fine.